# Getting error in installing laravel 5.2 in ubuntu 14

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting this error when installing laravel 5.2 on ubuntu 14. I have used this following command to install php

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-gd
```

But after getting installed some part of laravel framework I am getting this following error:

```
  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:


         - /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
            - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini

      You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```